# Preserve Elm compiler error colors when running Elm app through webpack-dev-server

Tags: compiler-errors, webpack, webpack-dev-server, elm

I'm writing an Elm app with webpack, and while `elm-reactor` has very nice error color styles, when webpack displays compiler errors, they're in all red and harder to read. Is there a way to tell webpack to preserve the colors set by the elm compiler?

Comment: Can you please specify which OS and terminal are you running?

Comment: macOS and the Terminal app running the Fish shell.

Answer (score 1):

This configuration enables colors for me:

```
var server =
   new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
      hot: true,
      stats: { colors: true }, //This line enable colors
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "../build"),
      headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }
  });

server.listen(env.PORT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about webpack-dev-server, but I do know that if you use `child_processes.spawn` (see [nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)), you can pass the `stdio: "inherit"` [option](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio) to preserve the exact output from the child process. I used it with `elm-make` and it works.

So I assume there would be some kind of way to apply this to webpack-dev-server?